# can't download .XLS file from url using selenium python. Always end up with Firefox download popup

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have tried various methods but I'm unable to download excel file. I always end up with the firefox popup staring at me. any Idea how to get this working

```
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # customlocation
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir','/home/rahul')
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.panel.shown', False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk','application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12,application/octet-stream')
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", False)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    driver.get('any_url')
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    time.sleep(5)
    export = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ExportSpn"))).click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: See the most upvoted answer. Possible duplicate of [Python: Unable to download with selenium in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072022/python-unable-to-download-with-selenium-in-webpage/44196146#44196146)

Comment: I got it done thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I was mentioning the MIME type wrong. The MIME type require the download file was 'application/ms-excel'. If someone still has problems getting MIME type wrong I would suggest https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe approach to get MIME type right.

•   manually download the file with Firefox checking the "automatically save this file type" checkbox
•   open Help -> Troubleshooting Information in firefox browser
•   locate the "Profile Folder" button, click it
•   inside the profile folder locate the mimeTypes.rdf file
•   open the file in a text editor and look for the mimetypes mentioned there - the XML node attribute values that start with urn:mimetype
•   use the mimetypes you found in the browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk comma-separated value