# Why is Firefox not using the profile preferences via selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to download a PDF files using Firefox in Selenium but the preferences I have set below do not seem to be working. Whenever I run the code, I am still getting the `"You have chosen to open:"` dialog box even though the preferences state that PDF files should automatically be downloaded.

Am I missing something?

```
def setUp(self):
    downloads_folder = initialSearch.download_path(self)

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloads_folder)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Unable to download with selenium in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072022/python-unable-to-download-with-selenium-in-webpage)

Comment: @DebanjanB, taking a look at this feed, I don't see anything here that would help me with this problem. I see the code cited in the last response to this question but it is almost identical to mine above which is why I am confused as to why I'm still getting the dialog box...

Comment: Your _Selenium_ version please?

Comment: I'm using selenium 3.8.1

Comment: i am having the exact same issue under java with same version. The issue arises after switching to firefox quantum. But I also still search for the right preference to disable the pdf viewer in quantum

Comment: any positive updates on this issue?

Answer (score -2):

Try this one `profile.update_preferences(`) before

> webdriver.Firefox(profile)

please may help you