# Webdriver - Can't use headless mode in Firefox when using preferences

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile, firefox-headless

I want to launch Firefox headlessly through Selenium, but I can't seem to find a way to do so and keep my preferences at the same time.

```
from selenium import webdriver;
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox;

cProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile();
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions();
dwnd_path = os.getcwd();

options.add_preference('browser.download.folderList', '2');
options.add_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', 'false');
options.add_preference('browser.download.dir', 'dwnd_path');
options.add_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel');
```

Running this, I will get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    options.add_preference('browser.download.folderList', '2');
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_preference'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_preference'
```

...implies that an instance of **Options** doesn't supports the attribute **add_preference**.

**add_preference** is supported by an instance of **FirefoxProfile()** only.

You can find a detailed discussion to use `add_preference` with an instance of `FirefoxProfile()` in [Python: Unable to download with selenium in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072022/python-unable-to-download-with-selenium-in-webpage/44196146#44196146)

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver;
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

cProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile();
dwnd_path = os.getcwd();
cProfile.add_preference('browser.download.folderList', '2');
cProfile.add_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', 'false');
cProfile.add_preference('browser.download.dir', 'dwnd_path');
cProfile.add_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel');
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=cProfile, firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on how to use the `headless` argument through an instance of `Options()` class in [How to make firefox headless programatically in Selenium with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)