# Create a new folder and make it as default download in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, datetime, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing a selenium test in python where I want to create a new directory with current time and make it as default download folder. So whenever I run the script the default download location should be a new directory created at that time and the file should download there.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
import os

today = datetime.now()

current_dir = os.mkdir("/Users/Desktop/" + today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Desktop/chromedriver')
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : current_dir }
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
```

I am running the above script and it creates a new folder but the default download location doesn't change as the file still downloads at chrome://Downloads. Is there any way we can change the new created folder as default download directory

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is with the `os.mkdir` method. The `os.mkdir()` method in Python is used to create a directory named path with the specified numeric mode. This method does not return any value.

Execution of the code with debugging:
[image]

If you look at the above image, you can see that the `current_dir` is of None type.
So, the folder is created on the desktop, but the path to it is not being captured.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create folder name and folder itself in two separate code lines:

```
current_dir_name = "/Users/Desktop/" + today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
os.mkdir(current_dir_name)
```

and then path `current_dir_name` into

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : current_dir_name}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a new directory with current time you can use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from datetime import datetime
  import os


  new_dir = "C:/Users/user-name/Desktop/" + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
  print(new_dir)
  if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
      os.makedirs(new_dir)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  C:\Users\user-name\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms>new_directory.py
  C:/Users/user-name/Desktop/2020-08-04_18-01-46

  C:\Users\user-name\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms>new_directory.py
  C:/Users/user-name/Desktop/2020-08-04_18-02-01

  C:\Users\user-name\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms>new_directory.py
  C:/Users/user-name/Desktop/2020-08-04_18-02-05
  ```
- Snapshot of the newly created directories:

[image: directories]

---

### This usecase

Now you can implement the same logic to create a new directory on each execution and set as the default download location using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
import os

new_dir = "C:/Users/user-name/Desktop/" + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
print(new_dir)
if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
    os.makedirs(new_dir) 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory" : new_dir})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Python: Unable to download with selenium in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072022/python-unable-to-download-with-selenium-in-webpage/44196146#44196146)