# Download an excel file using a command line tools

Tags: bash, selenium, curl, wget

I would like to use a tool from the command line to fetch the file that can be manually downloaded by clicking on the ***Export to Excel*** link present in the following page on the right.

https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym=700&sc_lang=en

I tried a few simply tools like wget or curl for this purpose, but with no luck because the url is masked. Can you suggest any tool that would do the job?

Thanks ìn advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym=700&sc_lang=en")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Export to Excel"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: download]

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much. I have just a quick question. Would it be possible to save the file directly to disk (no prompt) without messing up with the firefox settings?

Comment: @Arturo I have tested the code and as of now it does just like that, no additional firefox settings required.

Comment: I guess you have already set in firefox how to handle this file type. Anyway, thank again for your help and assistance-

Comment: Ahh, I tested it on Chrome. If you are using a `FirefoxProfile` check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072022/python-unable-to-download-with-selenium-in-webpage/44196146#44196146)